# Set value of ember select from event

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, ember.js

I have an Ember.Select which I've extended in order to encapsulate the options & some logic when things change.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to set the value (i.e. the selected index) of the Ember.Select when an event is triggered by the controller.  I've created a jsbin here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/avoXOnOd/5/edit

You'll notice that when you enter a number in the textbox (say 3 for example) and click on the button next to it, the console is displaying the correct value, but the selected index of the select does not change.  What I'm after is to be able to change the selection when an event is triggered by the controller.

Comment: What does `[evented]` actually mean, and how don't *any* of the *dozens* of other event-related tags apply here?  If you insist on it existing, please add a tag wiki that explains how to use it, then add the tag to questions that need it.

Comment: evented refers to 'Ember.Evented' which is used to trigger events in Ember.  Not sure how to create a tag wiki, but I'd be happy to do it if you can point me to a starting point.  You can see it referenced in the jsbin.

Comment: Aha! A much better tag name would be `[ember.evented]` -- "evented" alone is way to unspecific, as the word can mean multiple things and has a typo collision with [eventd](http://www.eventd.org/).  To start a tag wiki, hover over the tag and click the "help us edit this wiki" link.

Comment: i can live w/ that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have updated the bin to make it work. [Link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/avoXOnOd/7/). Fore more information, refer to `selection` attribute in `Ember.Select` [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html).

I have reduced the number of options, and the selected option would be 1 plus the entered number. So input 0-3 in the text box to see it working